# Apollo client - mutation detect mutation completion and then run code

Tags: reactjs, graph, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am trying to implement an update function and therefore, I am using GraphQL mutation. However, I need to be able to detect when a mutation completes so I can run a refresh function.

So far for the mutation I have:

```
const handleParameterUpdate = () => {
    let active = true;

    (async() => {
 
        await updateParameterMutation({variables: {
           parameterId: props.parameter.id, 
           newField: newFieldValue;
        }});

        if (!active) {
            return;
        }
        
    })().then(props.updateParams());
    
}
```

Inside my parent component I have:

```
const handleRefresh = () => {
    refetchJobParams({
        id: parent.id
    });
}
```

My intention is to run the `handleRefresh` function after the mutation is completed. So far it immediately runs after the `handleParametersUpdate` therefore, I need to refresh to get new the new parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your useMutation here. However, there's an option for the `useMutation` hook to add a `onCompleted` callback which will get called on success. If you're also refetching something from an apollo query, then I can suggest that you also use `refetchQueries` options. This lets you write less code & let Apollo handle deal with the refetching & completion callbacks.

[Mutation options (onCompleted & refetchQueries)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options)

With your code though, if you wanted to run `handleRefresh` inside `handleParameterUpdate`, then you can extract whatever value is returned by your mutation.

```
const handleParameterUpdate = async () => {    
    const returnValue = await updateParameterMutation({variables: {
       parameterId: props.parameter.id, 
       newField: newFieldValue;
    }});

    // whatever check you need to do on your mutation,
    if (returnValue){
        handleRefresh();
    }
}
```